# Right way of intoducing yourself in a presentation

Tags: grammar

I know that if someone is on the phone, they should say `This is [] speaking` instead of `I am []` as it is a rule in English language. However, my question is that in the case of a formal presentation, either using **virtual** presentation using `share screen` or the actual face to face presentation, how the presenter should introduce him/herself?

Answer (score 3):

Try "My name is []."  The viewer/attendee to the presentation will clearly see it is a person speaking to them.

Comment: What if it is a virtual presentation like what I said in my question?

Comment: The share-screen still shows a person's face allowing the viewer to see the person who is speaking.  The same answer applies.  Additionally, as it is a professional/formal presentation, it is also recommended that the introduction give the last name and inform the viewers/audience members of the speaker's role, qualifications, or background, e.g. "My name is Robert Simpson, Director of Operations at ACME, Inc."

Comment: Not really, in my case, it only shows the screen and not the face. So, if the voice of presenter is only available,  I should say This is [] speaking? or still my name is []?

Comment: "My name is ____" is the general way of introducing yourself in any presentation. "This is ____ speaking" sounds too much like you're on the telephone, which you're not--you're giving a presentation.

Comment: @Yee-Lum Understood. Thanks for the advice.